# Make directives without attributes, but embedded HTML in view. But without jQuery.

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm reading an article on transclusion and have got to about here [here](http://teropa.info/blog/2015/06/09/transclusion.html#transcluding-from-a-parent-directive). At this point, the author has said that making a directive in this way

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            logoSrc: '@',
            header: '@',
            body: '@'
        }
    };
});

<my-directive header="header"
              body="body"
              logo-src="logoSrc.png">
</my-directive>
```

Is awkward and not desirable. It suggests instead to make the HTML inside the tag

```
app.directive('myCard', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      title: '=myTitle',
      pic: '=myPic'
    },
    templateUrl: 'myCard',
    transclude: true,
    link: function(scope, el, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
      el.find('.content').append(transclude());
    }
  };
});
```

Is it necessary to use jQuery and DOM manipulation to use directives this way? Is there really any advantage other than cleaner looking templates which don't need to be appended in this way?

Comment: The only jQuery-ish thing here is `.find` and `.append` - both are part of jqLite of Angular. So, the question is really not about jQuery or not, but how best to have the user of the directive specify its template. In most cases, the second approach is preferable to passing HTML-as-string via attribute binding, especially since it could also have directives and expressions. And, although off-topic, `.append(transclude());` is less preferable than `transclude(function(clone){ element.append(clone); })`

Comment: jqLite supports only find element by tagName. In this question selector is class find('.content'). I believe @thomas included jQuery plugin.

Comment: @JagadeshK I didn't include any jQuery or plugin. The only jQuery is from the article i linked.